# Integer v/s int

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive

Read this on the oracle docs [java.lang](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) page:

> Frequently it is necessary to represent a value of primitive type as if it were an object. The wrapper classes `Boolean`, `Character`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, and `Double` serve this purpose.

I'm not sure I understand why these are needed. It says they have useful functions such as `equals()`. But if I can do `(a==b)`, why would I ever want to declare them as `Integer`, use more memory and use `equals()`? How does the memory usage differ for the 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Java's generics system](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) only supports class types.  And since primitives are not classes, they  can't be used with generics.  However, a primitive's wrapper class can be used as a generic type.  For example, you may not declare an `ArrayList<int>`, but you can achieve a similar functionality with an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

It is also of occasional use to initialize a variable's value to `null`.  Primitives, however, cannot be set to `null`; that privilege is reserved for objects.

```
// This is OK
Integer iDontKnowValueYet = null;

// Compile error!
int iDontKnowThisYetEither = null;
```

Comment: +1 Even before generics, Collections, Lists, Sets and Maps only stored objects.

Comment: I see. But why would Java designers design generics to not work with primitives and int to not be set to null while being initialized, they must have seen something useful in using Integer more than int?

Comment: The fact that collections doesn's accept primitives has nothing to do with generics.

Answer (score 1):

Things like int, char, double are all primitives meaning they do not need to be instantiated by using "new".  Things like Integer, Character, Double are objects that take up more room on the computer (since there is more overhead for objects) but you can use methods like Integer.parse().  In general, use the primitives and only use the object versions if you need one of the methods.

To answer the thing about a==b vs a.equals(b):

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = new Integer(5);
```

Even though they are the same value (which is what .equals tests for) they are not the same piece of memory since you said "new" twice.  a!=b but a.equals(b)

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = a;
```

Now they use the same piece of memory meaning if you change one, you change them both (unless you use "new" again).  a==b and a.equals(b)

```
//using last code block
b = new Integer(5);
```

Now once again a!=b but a.equals(b)==true since once again they have the same value but they are on different pieces of memory.

Comment: Two things. First, Integer.parse can be used for primitive types too. In fact Integer.parseInt returns int instead of Integer. Second, you cannot change variable 'a' as you suggest because Integer is an immutable class.

Comment: @axelrod360 I see so equals can be used to compare values as compared to comparing references.
and I guess Integer has the parseInt defined in it, so it can be called from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your ints are usually wrapped in wrapper classes when you put them in a data structure. So, .equals method is used to determine when you call .contains method on the data structure.

Other usefule methods:
toString
toHexString
parseString